# Microsoft Access 2007 - Auto insert start/end time

Tags: database, ms-access-2007

I have a table including **start** **time** & **end** **time** fields. I want to insert the start time, that should be automatically appears when I type something in a row. And I want to insert end time, that also should be automatically appears when i go to the next row.

I have entered as `time()` in default value from the design view. But I get start time & end time as same. That is not right. What is the correct method to fix this.

Can any one help to me?

Comment: I don't think you can do the 'end time' if you are updating directly into a table. If you use a form, then thee are events that will support what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Wayne is right as long as you are entering information directly into the table, I do not believe there is anything you can do to record the end time. If you want to use a form this would be possible. Forms are generally better for data entry anyway.

The event you would probably want to use would be "After Update" (ie. After one of the fields change) you could either use the code after the last field (ie. only show end time when the last field is entered or changed) or for every field (this will give the last time any field was updated regardless of order)

The code would look like this (with your actual fields):

```
Private Sub Field_Name_AfterUpdate()
Me![end time] = Now()
End Sub
```

You can find the events from the design view click on the field and open the property sheet then go to the event tab and click on the "..." the go to code builder and you would just add the line of code in the middle (make sure the field name matches exactly) (it will automatically add the first and last line)

===========================================

Edit:

Ok so three main things are stopping you right now. I know this can be really difficult when you start, but as soon as you get it to work it will feel amazing.

First - you do NOT want to place the code under starttijd because that field just starts with the default value and never changes. Thus putting code on the Before update or After update will not run. You need to place this in the fields that are updated (ie the fields people fill out with the form) So if they fill out a name for example then you would place the code there

Second - The code is meant to update the END time not the start time ie Me![END]=Now() not Me![starttijd]=Now()

Third - The code you will want to run on After update not before update. Though this is not as important as the above two